# Eclipse Link - Join Fetch vs fetching on demand in Lazy Fetchtype relationship

Tags: jpa, orm, eclipselink

I use Eclipse Link as the JPA provider in my project.

Assume that I have the relationship in EntityA set as follows:

```
Public class EntityA {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=OtherEntity.class, mappedBy="someColumn")
    private Set<OtherEntity> otherEntities;
}
```

I don't want to change the FetchType to `EAGOR` because most of the times I don't need to access the `otherEntities`. 
My question is when I do need to access `otherEntities`, does it make a difference from performance perspective to use FETCH JOIN in my query or just let the entity manager fetch the `otherEntities` whenever it is accessing it in the code: `entityA.getOtherEntities()`. How does Eclipse Link handle it?

Comment: This seems straight forward and covered anywhere that joins are described, so I'm not sure that i'm not missing something.  Using a fetch join causes the relationed entities to be brought in with a single query, while not using a fetch join means a separate query is used.  So it depends on the SQL generated for the join and your database, but usually a single query is more efficient then two.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read somewhere that using fetch joins on a collection association results in duplicates and can impact performance if the result set is large. So I'm not sure if making a round trip to db whenever `entityA.getOtherEntities()` is more efficient or using fetch join even though there might be duplicates

Comment: you will have to test it out, as there are no absolutes - it all depends on the initial query, your database and all the options/mappings you are using in addition to the number of rows involved.